# Button to mark as complete, then add to a completed list

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rails newbie, so excuse basic question.

I'm looking to create a button (e.g. "Do this") that when clicked by a user marks that action as completed. The action is then added to a list in the user's profile.

I think I need to have a Boolean on the action, to check whether the action is completed or not, but how can I work it so multiple users can complete the same action?

Any links to tutorials or railscasts appreciated!

Comment: I'm afraid this is not a real question. Too general to give a specific answer.

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/390-turbolinks  the cast has another main subject, but it shows an exemple based on complete tasks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me suppose, that "action" is model `UserAction`. (do not advice your to call it just "Action" because it may conflict with ActionController Module).

Then comes `new` method in `user_actions_controller`, with related `new.html.erb` in user_actions views folder.

```
def new
@user_action=UserAction.new
end
```

On following link Rails will fetch `new.html.erb`, it should contain

```
<%= form_for @user_action do |f| %>
<%= f.label :kind_of %>
<%=f.text_field :kind_of %>
<%=f.submit%>
```

Where `kind_of` -db column of `UserAction`.

On submitting new user_action will be saved in database (difference between new and create is important).

But actually, all these helpers just produce html code for you. There are many of them.

`form_for` is common model helper, which does a lot of stuff in background - sends submit as POST request, and create method in controller deals with it.

But you can check out more in rails api tutorial.